# Build version Vs MinSdk Vs targetSdk

Tags: android

Everytime  I get confused with this and I do search and I "think" I understood it but I appear not too.

Can someone explain to me whats the difference between the API you are building against and Min SDK you specify in your manifest and the target SDK you specify.

For example:
I have an application that its minSDK is 8 and targetSDK is 15 and I build against SDK 12. What's the difference? What devices does it run on? What do I gain from these differences!
Someone please explain!
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of both target API and minSDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755598/what-is-the-purpose-of-both-target-api-and-minsdk)

Comment: Thx for the downvote and no it's not a duplicate and that thread is over 2years ago.chances are things have changed with tablets

Comment: I didn't downvote, but thanks for assuming. Also, no things have not likely changed with tablets. The meaning of these two are exactly the same as they used to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference?

The difference is the result of subtracting two numbers. But that's not important here. :-)

> What devices does it run on?

That depends on your code as much as anything else. However, it will *not* run on API Level 7 and below, as those fall below your `minSdkVersion`. Android devices (and markets) will not allow your app on API Level 7 and lower devices.

> What do I gain from these differences!

By setting a build target of 12, you are saying to the compiler and build tools: "I want to use APIs newer than those from API Level 8, up through API Level 12, but I promise to do so in such a way as to avoid those newer APIs on the older devices". The build tools, Lint in particular, will yell at you when you try using newer APIs without appropriate protection (e.g., checking `android.os.Build.SDK_INT`).

By setting `android:targetSdkVersion` to 15, you are saying to the compiler and build tools: "When I wrote this code, I was thinking about API Level 15". Devices *newer* than your target may elect to do things differently, to try to better emulate life back on API Level 15.

The best example of the latter is `AsyncTask`. Traditionally, tasks could run in parallel. However, *if* you have `android:targetSdkVersion` set to 13 or higher, *and* you are running on an API Level 13 or higher device, *then* tasks will execute serially by default. If you run on an a device that is API Level 13 or higher, but your `android:targetSdkVersion` is 12 or lower, the device will fall back to the old behavior, to maintain compatibility.

Comment: Thank you.as always love your explanations.Ok if I want to have my app running on api 8 and higher without using the build tool then what should I do? Build against 8 and set minsdk to 8 but have targetsdk to highest number?

Comment: @Snake: "Ok if I want to have my app running on api 8 and higher without using the build tool then what should I do?" -- I have no idea what "without using the build tool" means.

Comment: I mean without using android.os.Build.SDK_INT and trying figure out what would work and what wouldn't

Comment: @Snake: The build tools, Lint in particular, will yell at you when you try using newer APIs. You have no choice but to use the build tools, unless you would like to stop writing Android apps. Set your `android:minSdkVersion` to 8. Set your build target to 8 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK you use to build your own application will define all the availables classes. There is no reason not to use the highest available (currently 17)

minSDK is, as mentioned by JoxTraex: "the minumum android OS set of APIs that your app requires at to work"

targetSDK is the highest build you have tested your apps. This will enable some features (Holo, Goodbye Menu button). These changes are introduced by default in new Android version, but you should write in your manifest that these new features have been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Min SDK is the minumum android OS set of APIs that your app requires at to work

Target SDK is the version that is your main platform target, this is typically always higher than the Min.

It does not decide devices as devices's platform version can change.